# What kind of chemical reaction happens when combining Tahini and Date syrup?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, mixtures, viscosity

While both Tahini and Date syrup are quite thin, when mixed together they form a paste-like substance that is very delicious, and quite thick. But what kind of chemical reaction leads to such sudden change in the viscosity of the mixture?

Comment: A reference found by googling: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.485.6346&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can easily Google it as demonstrated by Apoorv Potnis.

Comment: After a quick inspection of the article linked to by Apoorv all I could see was a report of physical characterization indicating that the mixture forms a thixotropic paste. It only confirms but does not explain the observation made by the OP. While the OP seems to be potentially misguided (looking for an explanation in the form of a "chemical reaction") there is potentially interesting and complex physical chemistry associated with the answer, which I'd like to see. Plus, I love tahini, I think I'll have it for lunch tomorrow now.

Comment: I’m glad I could spark some interest in Tahini!  On a more serious note, I did see the mentioned paper, but I found no answer to this question in it. Forgive me if the question is a bit vague. Chemistry is not really my field of study. I’m just a very curious fat guy not unlike Winnie the pooh.

Comment: This is a halvah question to ask!

Comment: Effects replicated with grape syrup instead of date syrup.